# Cannot catch ADException in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, exception, active-directory

I'm using the ActiveDirectory Powershell module to add some groups to our domain. During this process, the script might attempt to add a user to a group they're already a member of. This is an exception that I should be able to handle, but, I cannot seem to catch it. No matter what I do, I see red text in the powershell console.

I simplified this all down to a few testable steps.

```
New-ADGroup -Path "ou=temp,dc=domain,dc=tld" -GroupScope Global -Identity testGroup
Get-ADGroup -Identity testGroup | Add-ADGroupMember -Members testUser
try
{
    Get-ADGroup -Identity testGroup | Add-ADGroupMember -Members testUser
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "Caught exception!"
}
```

I expect to see "Caught exception!" in yellow text, however, what I actually get is:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : The specified account name is already a member of the group At line:1 char:40
+ try {Get-ADGroup -Identity testGroup | Add-ADGroupMember -Members testUser} ca ...
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=testGroup,OU=Temp,DC=domain,DC=tld:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified account name is already a member of the group,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

All in red text.

I expect that I'm overlooking something simple. I'd appreciate any input.

Edit: PS version information as requested:

```
C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18331
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: What PowerShell version are you running?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm on PS version 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Add-ADGroupMember` supports the common cmdlet parameters. I would try adding `-ErrorAction Stop` and see if that allows it to be caught. This works, for example, with other cmdlets like `Get-Content`:

```
try { gc "NotAFile.txt" } catch { write-warning $_ }
```

will write an error, but

```
try { gc "NotAFile.txt" -ErrorAction Stop } catch { write-warning $_ }
```

writes a warning.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it. Good thinking, though. I've been bit by that before.

Comment: Appending `-EA Stop` to `Add-ADGroupMember` did work for me. If it doesn't work for you, try setting `$global:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`.

Comment: Whoops, it appears that I added the -EA Stop parameter to the wrong cmdlet; that's quite embarrassing. I am curious, however, as to why Adil H.'s example does not require this to function as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure something else is not going on there? It works just fine for me:

```
PS H:\> try { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "testgroup" -members (get-adcomputer MyComputerName) } catch {Write-Warning "$_"}
WARNING: The specified account name is already a member of the group
```

Comment: You're right, that code works. It seems to have something to do with the pipe.